# How to display image duplicate count from prompt in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, prompt

I want to display a certain amount of duplicates for 2 seperate images. The web page prompts the user for the speed, which i have done, and for how many duplicates of each image they want.

```js
function show_image() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  var img2 = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "map.png";
  img2.src = "figure-front.png";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  document.body.appendChild(img2);
  setTimeout("show_image()", speed);
  max = 0;
  max++
  if (max = count) {
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript Slide Show</title>
  <script src="ShowImages3.js"></script>
  <script>
    var speed = prompt("Type how fast you want to duplicate", " ");
    var count = prompt("Type how many image of each you want to duplicate", " ");
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="show_image()">

</body>

</html>
```

However as you can see it runs infinitely apparently

Comment: It runs infinitely because every call calls `setTimeout`. Move your `setTimeout` to the `else` statement at the bottom.

Comment: `if (max = count)` do you know what `=` does in JS? You meant: `if (max === count)`. Then, obviously, each time you call again `show_image` (which BTW should be `setTimeout(show_image, speed);`) you're setting again `max = 0` - so it will always be `0`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan And even if he wouldn't reset it, his `return` won't do anything (it was going to anyway) and the setTimeout needs to be moved. Also, passing a string into setTimeout is valid. Not commonly done, but technically valid.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Wow i felt really dumb reading your comment, i'll keep that in mind for later thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to move the setTimeout and use `==` or `===` for comparison. `=` is assignment

It is not recommended to use body onload for anything. Instead use an eventListener.

Here is a cleaner version using setInterval. Also I use >= for the test

And I assign an empty string to the speed and prompt values so I can test using if (speed && prompt) after converting to number using the unary plus. I did not add testing for other than numbers and empty string by the way.

```js
let count = 0, cnt = 0, tId;

const show_image = () => {
  if (cnt >= count) {
    clearInterval(tId); // stop
    return;
  }
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  const img2 = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "map.png";
  img2.src = "figure-front.png";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  document.body.appendChild(img2);
  cnt++; // next
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let speed = +prompt("Type how fast you want to duplicate", "");
  count = +prompt("Type how many image of each you want to duplicate", "");

  if (speed && prompt) tId = setInterval(show_image, speed)

});
```

Or have this which encapsulates the variables

```js
const generate = (count, speed) => {
  let cnt = 0;
  let tId;

  const addImages = () => {
    if (cnt >= count) {
      clearInterval(tId); // stop
      return;
    }
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const img2 = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "map.png";
    img2.src = "figure-front.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(img2);
    cnt++; // next
  };

  tId = setInterval(addImages, speed);
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let speed = +prompt("Type how fast you want to duplicate", "");
  let count = +prompt("Type how many image of each you want to duplicate", "");

  if (speed && count) {
    generate(count, speed);
  }
});
```

Comment: Even cleaner to pass `speed`, `count`, and `cnt` to `show_image` so you're not dependent on globals...

Comment: @HereticMonkey See added version